# Syntax for using datatype indexed by Nat

Tags: haskell, syntax, data-kinds, refinement-type, liquid-haskell

The following code tries to refine Clash's `Unsigned` type family at index `4` into `Digit`:

```
import Clash.Prelude

{-@ type Digit = {v : Unsigned 4 | v <= 9 } @-}
type Digit = Unsigned 4

{-@ foo :: Digit -> Digit @-}
foo = id @Digit
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
The Liquid type
.
    (Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned {4}) -> (Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned {4})
.
is inconsistent with the Haskell type
.
    Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned 4
-> Clash.Sized.Internal.Unsigned.Unsigned 4
.
defined at src/HelloClash.hs:11:1-3
.
Specifically, the Liquid component
.
    {4}
.
is inconsistent with the Haskell component
.
    GHC.Types.Int
.
```

So it seems the `4` in `Unsigned 4` is parsed by LH as something special other than a Haskell type-level `Nat`. What is the correct syntax to "escape" (or, rather, *un-escape?*) the `4` so that it is parsed as part of the type constructor application?